# ASPX Textbox value unchanged if there is earlier data

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASPX form with a TextBox object.

It is defined in the code behind as `public TextBox UI_Delegate1;` and in the ASPX form as `<ASP:TextBox id="UI_Delegate1" runat="server" />`

At the `Page_Load` member in the code behind, I make the assignment:

```
UI_Delegate.Text = "AnyText";
```

The rendered HTML text for this control is:

```
<input name="UI_Delegate1" type="text" value="AnyText" id="UI_Delegate1" />
```

Within the form, I have a button with this definition:

```
<button type="submit" onserverclick="SubmitChanges" runat="server">Submit Changes</button>
```

I then type text in the TextBox, to modify the "AnyText" value to some other text and then click the Submit Changes button, but the value of UI_Delegate1.Text in the code behind SubmitChanges member after clicking the button continues to be "AnyText", no matter what I type.

In other words, it seems that ASPX is considering this control as readonly, but I have not set such attribute anywhere.

What could be the possible reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: Is this code executed only on initial page load? `UI_Delegate.Text = "AnyText";` i.e. is it placed in `if(!IsPostBack)` block?

Comment: The code that initializes the TextBox Text property is placed in protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e).  There is no a if(!IsPostBack) block in Page_Load.

Comment: @Yuriy has the right idea... you need to make sure you're only setting  Text if the page hasn't been posted back to itself.

Comment: Do you mean that Page_Load is called somehow between the click on "Submit Changes" and the execution of server-side function "SubmitChanges"?  In the SubmitChanges function I am saving to disk an XML file, then I redirect to the same file and then load the saved XML file at Page_Load.  My expectation is that Page_Load is not executed until I call Response.Redirect(SamePage);

Comment: Here is an [overview of the life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) of an ASP.NET Page. Notice in particular that Load happens on every request, just before processing Postback event handling. So your Page_Load event handler needs to take into consideration whether the page is being loaded for a first request (an HTTP GET) or if it's in response to an HTTP POST from itself. The way you make that determination is by checking IsPostBack, which is a property on the Page object.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, Rick. I guess that the instant gratification of being able to (apparently) build something so quickly with ASP.NET made me skip reading the most essential basics (my background is from Delphi and I am not a professional developer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Yuriy said, make the following change in Page_Load:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  UI_Delegate1.Text = "AnyText";
}
```

Comment: I seem to be missing how PostBack works, but this definitively fixes the behaviour.